# mongodb sasl unable to find a callback 32775

Tags: mongodb, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

I installed a MongoDB server 4.0 Enterprise Edition on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and configured kerberos authentication following the official documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-windows-with-kerberos-authentication/

When I tried to connect to the MongoDB server from a client the authentication failed and I've got this error in the MongoDB server log file:

**2018-07-19T16:12:00.622+0200 I ACCESS   [conn4] SASL GSSAPI authentication failed for .... on $external from client .... ; BadValue: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 32775**

Did I miss something ?